# Delete oldest deployment in a namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I have two deployments running in one namespace with name deployment-A and deployment-B.

Currently, it is configured in such a way that if A is running then my Jenkins job will deploy B and vice-versa. But the job fails when both A and B are running. 
Now I want it to modify a bit so that if both A and B are running then the job should delete the oldest one (based on their deployment time).

I know it can be achieved with some shell script but not able to figure out the exact command.

Comment: "Currently, it is configured...", you have done that using `kubectl` or Kubernetes API or accessing deployment A/B (to check whether deployment A/B exists)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is command for you:

`kubectl delete deployment $(kubectl get deployments --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o json | jq -r .items[0].metadata.name)`

Explanation: get all deployments sorted by timestamp, lower timestamp = older deployment, so first element is the oldest deployment. Than using json output and jq linux tool just get name of that deployment and pass it to delete deployment command.

Comment: P.S. I would really appreciate if you could accept my answer if it works for you :)